# Angular JS example for combining modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I'm new to Angular JS and trying out the examples on the projects [webpage](https://angularjs.org/). The examples them self are running good, but now I want to get one step further and include multiple modules in one page to increase reuse for the individual modules.

On the angular webpage's HTML source I find at the places, where the examples are included e.g. for the hello and the todo examples:

```
…
<div app-run="hello.html" class="well"></div>
…
<div app-run="todo.html" module="todoApp" class="well"></div>
…
```

but just using those lines in an `index.html` (which includes Angular JS) and providing the according `hello.html` and `todo.html` doesn't work.

How can I separate Angular JS modules in independent files and include them in a common webpage. (Maybe this is also relevant: later, I'd like to let the individual components talk to each other e.g. by using some shared parent state)

Comment: By 'modules' do you mean separate sections of HTML along with corresponding data and logic (ie: controllers)? Reusable components basically?

Comment: Yes, basically I mean "reusable components" which is modules as of modularization. I'm not familiar with the Angular JS terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to modularize your Angular app into components is to use [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Directives are one of the most powerful features of Angular and allow you to build reusable components each with their own HTML template and controller.

A very generic example of this would be a simple webpage with a custom navbar, sign-up box, and features section. Your HTML for a page such as this could look something like this:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-sign-up></app-sign-up>
<app-features-panel></app-features-panel>
```

...where `app` is simple a generic name. I typically abbreviate the name of whatever app I am building and prepend all my directive names with this. For example, for a `game` app I may call my navbar `<gm-navbar>`.

Now you can build out each directive similar to this:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('appSignUp', appSignUp);

function appSignUp() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'app/appSignUp/appSignUp.directive.html',
    link: link,
    controller: AppSignUpController,
    controllerAs: 'signUp'
  };

  return directive;

  function link(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
    // perform DOM manipulation here
  }
}
```

Let's briefly walk through the above Directive Definition Object (commonly abbreviated as DDO):

• `restrict: 'E'` simply means this directive is restricted to be an Element directive of the form `<app-sign-up>`. Note the dashes between words in the HTML, but camelCase in the Javascript. This is necessary as HTML does not recognize camel casing. Angular knows that `appSignUp` in the JS will refer to `app-sign-up` in the HTML.

• `templateUrl` simply references the path where your HTML template for this directive lives.

• `link` references your link function where you should perform any DOM manipulation. Note: Angular comes with a subset of jQuery called [`jqLite`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which you can use to manipulate the DOM.

• `controller` simply references the controller attached to this directive whose responsibility is mainly to attach your data to the DOM.

• `controllerAs` is an optional property which allows you to set an 'alias' for your controller. This way you can attach data to your scope using `signUp.pieceOfData` which makes your HTML even more specific and clear.

As for allowing individual components (directives) to talk to each other I would recommend creating Angular [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to GET and SET data within your app and then injecting these services into your controllers using [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). You mentioned 'parent state' and technically you could attach data to the `$rootScope` which is the root scope of your entire app which every directive will have access to. However, I urge you not to do this as you will pollute the global scope, and this is not the 'Angular way' to accomplish sharing state between controllers, services are.